# Could not connect sessionID 1 to sessionname console, Error code 7045

Tags: windows, batch-file, azure-devops, remote-desktop

I have created a self-hosted agent machine in an interactive mode (Windows 10) to run the unit tests. To disconnect from the Remote Desktop Connections while Running Automated Tests I am executing the below command from a command-line task (from Azure DevOps). This is working fine when the user logged into the agent machine. But getting an error If there is no user logged into that agent machine.

Is this expected behavior? Can we bypass this?

`%windir%\System32\tscon.exe 1 /dest:console`

**Error:**

```
Could not connect sessionID 1 to sessionname console, Error code 7045
Error [7045]: The requested session access is denied.
```

I tried with the other options as well like creating a batch file with the below code and executing it while running the pipeline.

This one is also giving the same error

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Command `query user %USERNAME%` will return the session even if the user is not currently logged in.

You can run command `query user ^| find "Active"` to query the active login users only.

See below:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%s in ('query user ^| find "Active" ') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console 
)
```

Comment: Hi @Lu, I have updated the .bat file to read the active users and close the RDP connections. Same error.

`Could not connect sessionID 3 to sessionname console, Error code 7045
Error [7045]:The requested session access is denied.`

Comment: @VINODKUMAR - were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `bat` file with the code:

```
(for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
))
```

which will close the RDP session and create a session with the Console as Active. You can check by executing the command `qwinsta`. Lets name that file `KeepSessionAlive.bat`.

Now, create one PowerShell script with the below code where we will check whether the console session is Active or not. If it's not active, then we will execute the above `bat` file, otherwise we won't.

```
$val = qwinsta
$flag = $True
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $val.Count; $i++) {
    if ($val[$i] -Match 'console'){
        if ($val[$i] -Match 'Active'){
            Write-Output $val[$i]
            $flag = $False
        }
    }
}
if ($flag){
    Write-Host "Activating Session"
    'Execute Bat file create above'
}
```

We can call the above PowerShell script in a pipeline and run our pipeline independently. Every time, it will check the status of the console session and, on the basis of that, it will execute the `bat` file (which will disconnect from the Remote Desktop Connections).

Comment: Hello.. With the help of above solution you can execute the code to disconnect the RDP session with any number of times through pipeline. Every time before executing it will check the status of console session through powershell script. If console session is not active than only it will execute the bat file