# I need to disconnect ane lock the vm and also session id to consloe

Tags: batch-file, automationanywhere

I'm getting error when I ran the batch file like this,

> Could not connect session Id 12 to session name console, error code 5
> Error [5]: access denied

and I'm attaching the batch file.

This is my code, I need disconnect ane lock the vm by using this batch file code

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
    %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
rem Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question and not as a screenshot and add more details about your issue.

Comment: Hi Nico, I put my code in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need and what I'm doing is **logoff** the session.

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, I want lock and disconnect can you please tell me how can I do, log off batch  file is running fine but as per my company policies auto login is won't use

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65389223/6906583 , and add this line at the end Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation

Comment: I attached one file right in that last line if I remove rem from that script system will lock but its not disconnected.